# non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member. Accessing boolean variable

Tags: c++, syntax

I've been searching for a while on why this does not work.  I have not gotten a clear answer.

Can anyone explain why trying to access this boolean variable and comparing it to another boolean variable won't work?

I also tried setting the `rhs` of the comparison to `0`, and that got rid of the boolean/int error, but I'm still getting the error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        setWorking(true);
    }

    //Mutator
    void setWorking(bool x) { working = x; }

    //Accessor
    bool getWorking() { return working; }

private:
    bool working;
};

int main() {

    MyClass alpha;

    if (alpha.getWorking == true) {
        cout << "its working\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "not working\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the parentheses: `alpha.getWorking()`

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: I cant believe I forgot ().  Ive been trying to fix this for almost 2 hours.  Thank you so much

Comment: You should also read and paste the error message

Comment: You also didn't bother searching for your error message. You would have found dozens of similar questions.

Comment: and please dont do `==true`

Answer (score 1):

In `main` function

```
if (alpha.getWorking == true)
```

should be

```
if (alpha.getWorking())
```

Comment: I think the comments already covered it...